# proper way assign numer to elements in a List Collection

Tags: c#

I am looping through a list of elements, and would like to assign a number to where each element resides in the Collection for deletion puposes. My code below, just gives me the count, is there another option to achieve this. Ex.

0 cat
1 dog
2 fish

ect..

```
        foreach (string x in localList)
        {
            {
                Console.WriteLine( localList.Count + " " + x);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use a for loop or use a separate index:

```
for(int i = 0; i < localList.Count;i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine( i + " " + localList[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that totally worked, I tried this earlier, but didn't use the .Count on the localList.

Answer (score 2):

be old school and go back to a standard for loop:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < localList.Count; ++i)
 {
    string x = localList[i];
    // i is the index of x
    Console.WriteLine(i + " " + x);
 }
```

Comment: LOL @ a for loop being "old school"

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to get fancy, you can use LINQ

```
foreach (var item in localList.Select((s, i) => new { Animal = s, Index = i }))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Index + " " + item.Animal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the collection type you are using you can use something like

```
foreach (string x in locallist)
{
    Console.WriteLine(locallist.IndexOf(x) + " " + x);
}
```

regds, perry